# Optimizing Scrapy xpath queries

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Does Scrapy ping the website every time I use response.xpath? Or is there one response value stored in memory per request and all subsequent xpath queries are run locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is stored in memory. That said, every time you call response.xpath it doesn't hit the website on the matter but memory.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that means assigning response to a local variable and driving the xpath queries off that doesn't really increase the efficiency of the scraper, either from the server's perspective or local memory...

Comment: Yes. Note: you can call `response.xpath` directly without assigning to a local variable

Comment: Thanks Andres! This answers my question exactly.

Comment: @JamesReade my pleasure. If it does, please accept it as the answer to your question.